# Is there a tool or a postgres feature that I can use to recreate google news alerts?

Tags: database, postgresql, search, indexing

I have `news_alerts` and `news_items` tables in postgres with the following index:

```
CREATE TABLE news_items (
  id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  content character varying
);
CREATE TABLE news_alerts (
  id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  user_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  terms character varying(255)
);
CREATE INDEX news_alerts_terms ON news_alerts
  USING gin (to_tsvector('english'::regconfig, (terms)::text));
```

And the following news alerts:

```
INSERT INTO news_alerts (user_id, terms) values (1, 'Jim Jarmusch');
INSERT INTO news_alerts (user_id, terms) values (1, 'Kim Kardashian');
INSERT INTO news_alerts (user_id, terms) values (2, 'Kim Kardashian');
```

When a new news item comes in, I add it to `news_items`:

```
INSERT INTO news_items (content) values ('Breaking: Kim Kardashian posts unconscionable new selfies from birthday party');
```

At this point, I want to alert the two users who have (however unwisely) chosen to receive Kim Kardashian news. I want to find all the `news_alerts` whose `terms` match the `content` of that `news_item` and notify those users.

Is there some way to do this with postgres indexes or even an external tool or service?

Comment: You'll attract more interest if you paste CREATE TABLE statements and a few INSERT statements for the relevant tables into your question (news_items and news_alerts tables, at the very least). Most of us *can* reverse-engineer tables from incomplete descriptions, but we don't always choose to invest our time that way.

Comment: thanks @MikeSherrill'CatRecall'. I added the table definitions. The INSERTs would be as expected.

Comment: @muirbot Could you post some inserts anyway? It would allow people who are interested to test without having to invent a dummy dataset by themselves.

Answer (score 1):

You can try abusing the ts_debug function. Gist is below. The `t` table would contain your news alerts. You probably should not directly use `ts_debug` - it is a sql language function, look at how it is implemented.

When you have lots of rows, you will not need to disable sequential scans. I did it just to show that an index can get used.

This is a bit terse, If you have questions, ask.

```
db=# create temp table t as select array_agg(distinct lexeme) as x from (select unnest(lexemes) as lexeme from ts_debug('english', 'Kim Kardashian')) a;
SELECT 1
db=# create index on t using gin(x);
CREATE INDEX
db=# set enable_seqscan to off;
SET
db=# select * from t where x <@ (select array_agg(distinct lexeme) as x from (select unnest(lexemes) as lexeme from ts_debug('english', 'Kim Kardashian is a woman')) a);
        x         
------------------
 {kardashian,kim}
(1 row)

db=# explain select * from t where x <@ (select array_agg(distinct lexeme) as x from (select unnest(lexemes) as lexeme from ts_debug('english', 'Kim Kardashian is a woman')) a);
                                    QUERY PLAN                                     
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Bitmap Heap Scan on t  (cost=1765.76..1769.78 rows=1 width=32)
   Recheck Cond: (x <@ $0)
   InitPlan 1 (returns $0)
     ->  Aggregate  (cost=1757.75..1757.76 rows=1 width=32)
           ->  Function Scan on ts_debug  (cost=0.25..507.75 rows=100000 width=32)
   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on t_x_idx  (cost=0.00..8.00 rows=1 width=0)
         Index Cond: (x <@ $0)
(7 rows)
```